# Let $\{W_t\}_{t \ge 0}$ be a Brownian motion. Determine whether $Y_t=e^{W_t^2 - t}$ is a martingale.

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, martingales

Let $\{W_t\}_{t \ge 0}$ be a Brownian motion. Determine whether $Y_t=e^{W_t^2 - t}$ is a martingale.

**Attempt:**

For $0\le s<t$,
\begin{align*}
E[Y_t|F_s] &= E[e^{W_t^2-t}|F_s] \\
&= E[e^{(W_t-W_s+W_s)^2 - t + s - s]}|F_s] \\
&= e^{-(t-s)} E[e^{(W_t-W_s)^2 + 2(W_t-W_s)W_s + W_s^2 - s}|F_s] \\
&= e^{-(t-s)} e^{W_s^2 - s} E[e^{(W_t-W_s)^2 + 2(W_t-W_s)W_s}| F_s] \\
&= e^{-(t-s)} e^{W_s^2 - s} e^{W_s} e^{2(t-s)} E[e^{(W_t-W_s)^2} | F_s] \\
&= e^{t-s} e^{W_s^2-s} e^{W_s} E[e^{(W_t-W_s)^2}|F_s].
\end{align*}

I got stucked here. What's next should I do? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: $EY_t=\infty$ if $t >\frac 1  2$.

Comment: @geetha290krm How to check whether a given stochastic process is martingale or not with the simple method before use the definition?

Comment: For $(Y_t)$ to be a martingale it is necessary that $EY_t <\infty$ for all $t$. (It is also necessary that $EY_t$ is independent of $t$).

Comment: @geetha290krm Wait. How do you conclude that $EY_t=\infty$ if $t > 1/2$?

Comment: @geetha290krm Could you explain to me please?

Comment: @PitikKepit . What always works is to calculate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{tx^2-t}e^{-x^2/2}\,dx\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. What is it? Where does it come from?

Comment: I am using the definition of a martingale to show that $(Y_t)$ is not martingale. The equation $E[Y_t|\mathcal F_s]=Y_s$ does not make sense if $EY_t=\infty$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes. But, how to calculate $EY_t=\infty$?

Comment: Just use the PDF of $N(0,1)$ and integrate $e^{tx^2}$ against it. Such calculations are normally taught before teaching studends what martingales are.